# How to resolve my warning in my custom service?

Tags: 8, symfony-services

I am getting the following error:

> Warning: Missing argument 1 for Drupal\custom_forms\Service\CustomFormsService::__construct(), called in /drupal/docroot/core/lib/Drupal/Component/DependencyInjection/Container.php on line 264 and defined in Drupal\custom_forms\Service\CustomFormsService->__construct() (line 13 of modules/custom_forms/src/Service/CustomFormsService.php).

And my code (`service.php`) is:

```
public function __construct($request) {
$this->cityname = \Drupal::request()->get('cityname');

if($this->cityname != ''){
  $result = \Drupal::database()->select('city_municipality','cm')
    ->fields('cm',array('municipality'))
    ->condition('city', $this->cityname)
    ->execute()->fetchAll();
    $result = json_encode($result);
    print $result; 
    exit;
 }
```

custom_forms_services.yml

```
  services:
       custom_forms.custom_forms_service:
           class: Drupal\custom_forms\Service\CustomFormsService
```

But the form functionalities are working fine.

Can anyone help me out on this?

Comment: Is this a service class or a form class? If it's a service class, what does your custom_forms.services.yml file look like? If it's a form class, do you have a function named create() in the class? If so, please show it.

Comment: custom_forms.services.yml                                                               services:
    custom_forms.custom_forms_service:
        class: Drupal\custom_forms\Service\CustomFormsService

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add an argument to your services.yml for the class to be injected:

```
services:
  custom_forms.custom_forms_service:
    class: Drupal\custom_forms\Service\CustomFormsService
    arguments:
      - @request_stack
```

Note that you should make a few changes to your service as well:

First, add an type hint for the argument:

```
public function __construct(\Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RequestStack $requestStack) {
```

Next, you will use the `$requestStack` instead of `Drupal::request()`:

```
$this->cityname = $requestStack->getCurrentRequest()->query->get('cityname');
```

Comment: I am getting the following error :Recoverable fatal error: Argument 1 passed to Drupal\custom_forms\Service\CustomFormsService::__construct() must be an instance of Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RequestStack, none given, called in /drupal/docroot/core/lib/Drupal/Component/DependencyInjection/Container.php on line 264 and defined in Drupal\custom_forms\Service\CustomFormsService->__construct() (line 14 of modules/custom_forms/src/Service/CustomFormsService.php).

Comment: You need to clear your cache.

Comment: I am getting the following error while clearing my cache..Fatal error: Call to undefined method Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RequestStack::get() in /drupal/docroot/modules/custom_forms/src/Service/CustomFormsService.php on line 16

Comment: Sorry, I think I had an error. I've updated the code. I should probably test before posting!

Comment: That warning message is gone now .But instead of that i am getting the following error:Warning: rename(sites/default/files/php/twig/.be1c355acf,sites/default/files/php/twig/3e3c5e84_form-element.html.twig_5aed6c86e745ca1542a2c5486a5ae6e3c10b65e3d3f0a67ca95f7fd6469d7f29/1d34fade5289c0f81a3172628c6ed246f4a79228989aea033170f08228f2f6e8.php): Operation not permitted in Drupal\Component\PhpStorage\MTimeProtectedFastFileStorage->save() (line 86 of core/lib/Drupal/Component/PhpStorage/MTimeProtectedFastFileStorage.php).

Comment: That has nothing to do with the current topic. So please mark this one as solved, and open a new topic for that error.